# If I have no user input, should use prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, security

I am currently working on the store page for my website. I am connecting  to my database where data for the products is stored. The page has no user input, it just displays the data such as product name, price etc. My question is, can/should I implement prepared statements in order to prevent from SQL injection. If I can't use prepared statements are there any other forms of security I should implement in my website?

Here is my current code:

```
    <?php

$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root','', 'cart');
$query = 'SELECT * FROM products ORDER by id ASC';
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

if ($result):
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0):
        while($product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)):
        ?>

            
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3" >
            <form method="post" action="view_product.php?action=add&id=<?php echo $product['id']?>">
                <div class="products"><a href="view_product.php?product=<?php echo $product['id'] ?>">
                    <img src="<?php echo $product['image'];?>" />
                    </a>
                    <h4 class="text-dark"><a href="view_product.php?product=<?php echo $product['id'] ?>">
                        <?php echo $product['name'];?>
                    </a>
                    </h4>
                    <h4><?php echo $product['price'];?></h4>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <?php
                    endwhile;
                endif;
          endif;
            ?>
```

When clicking on a certain product it redirects to another page where additional info is displayed for the particular product. I am using a query for that, could I use prepared statements for it?

```
<?php
$query = 'SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = "'.$_GET['product'].'"';
?>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Yes, should always use prepared statements. Note that the `$_GET` value (from the link) can be changed by a user through the browser URL or browser element edit.

Comment: IMO you should _always_ use prepared statements if you are passing a value to your query. Even if the value can in no way be changed by an external party, it still is better for performance and and lessens the chance of accidentally introducing an SQL Injection vulnerability. (And like Paul T. said, in this case it _is_ a vulnerability.)